# Beautiful Soup not finding element by ID

Tags: python-3.x, macos, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape incoming headlines from forexfactory.com.

```
from bs4 import *
import requests

source = requests.get("https://www.forexfactory.com/news").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

list = soup.find(id="ui-outer")

print(list)
```

This returns None when it should return the Div containing all the headlines.  Any idea what would be wrong?  I have tried searching by div, by Ul id, by li id and some other ways.  It always returns None.
Thank You.

Comment: I checked that website. Although the website does possess a `div` with `id=ui-outer`- when you print the full variable of `soup` from your code it does not have that div in it..... this could be a security thing where that website does not allow scraping of its data.

Comment: The website uses Cloudflare to protect from scripts and bots. You need to bypass it in order to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For dynamically created elements give [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) a try**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
URL = 'https://www.forexfactory.com/news'

driver.get(URL)
```

**Wait a few seconds until also dynamically content is loaded**

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # wait for seconds
```

**Get your element**

```
uiOuter = driver.find_element_by_id('ui-outer')
```

**Example for all links (story tile)**

```
aHref = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.flexposts__story-title a')
[x.text for x in aHref]
```

**Output**

```
    ['EU\'s Barnier says "fundamental divergences" persist in UK trade talks',
 'With end of crisis programs, Fed faces tricky post-pandemic transition',
 'Markets Look Past Near-Term Challenges',
 'Time is short, Divergences remain, but we continue to work hard for a deal',
 'EURUSD consolidates around 1.1900; indicators are flat',
 'Rush for emerging market company bonds as investors look beyond COVID-19',
 'Europe’s Virus Lockdowns Push Economy Into Another Contraction',
 'Interactive Brokers enhances Client Portal',
 'BoE’s Haldane: Risk That Anxiety Leads To Gloom Loop',
 'Sharpest fall in UK private sector output since May. Manufacturing growth offset by renewed...',
 'Remote Working Shift Offers Silver Lining for Finance Gender Gap',
 'EU Flash PMI signals steep downturn in November amid COVID-19 lockdowns',
 'German PMI drops to five-month low in November due to tightening of COVID-19 restrictions, but...',
 'Sharp decline in French business activity amid fresh COVID-19 lockdown',
 'Rishi Sunak says Spending Review will not spell austerity',
 'Remote Working Shift Offers Silver Lining for Finance Gender Gap',
 'Japan’s Labor Thanksgiving Day goes viral',
 'Ranking Asset Classes by Historical Returns (1985-2020)',
 'Time is short, Divergences remain, but we continue to work hard for a deal',
 'EURUSD consolidates around 1.1900; indicators are flat',
 'US Dollar stuck near support, NZ$ strikes two-year high',
 'US Dollar stuck near support, NZ$ strikes two-year high',
 'Georgia confirms results in latest setback for Trump bid to overturn Biden win',
 'Canada to roll over terms of EU trade deal with UK',
 'Time is short, Divergences remain, but we continue to work hard for a deal',
 'German PMI drops to five-month low in November due to tightening of COVID-19 restrictions, but...',
 "COVID-19: 'No return to austerity', says chancellor as he hints at public sector pay freeze",
 'EURUSD consolidates around 1.1900; indicators are flat',
 'New Zealand Dollar May Rise as RBNZ Holds Fire on Negative Rates',
 'Interactive Brokers enhances Client Portal']
```

Comment: Yes thank you, that worked beautifully.  Do you know how I can include the links with each respective article?  Thanks again.

Comment: @RehanMahmood - Fine, if you mean the urls in `href`, same procedure only with `x.get_attribute("href")`